# How to wake up "waiting" thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am making an app that is intended to emulate how packets are transmitted over the internet, and so some packets get lost.

The main thread waits for the response, however there has to be a timeout.

I want to have have a timer running in a thread, which interrupts the main thread if the timer times out. I am wondering if you can have both processes running concurrently, i.e. without making one sleep.

Comment: Oracle provides wonderful tutorials and documentation; you may want to read it: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: The basic idea behind threads is that they ... *are* run concurrently (or at least interleaved to appear so ;-). I believe there is a slightly different question here dealing with the interactions, that could be flushed out more: I have updated the title with where I *believe* the question is/was going...

Answer (score 0):

The very reason for threads to exist in java is so that they can run in parallel. Yes, two threads can run in parallel. For your program they are running in parallel. for CPU they may or may not depending on number of Cores you have.

Comment: I am unsure how that would work, if I use sleep() then the timer doesn't increment. The real issue is there is a socket.receive(), which is waiting for a packet, but the packet might never come, thus the process is blocked. I don't necessarily have to use threads, is there any other way to make sure I'm only waiting for the packet for a certain time.

Comment: The method SetSoTimeout(), does something to the effect I need.